# Alternate Reality World of the movie the Invention of Lying - Why no fiction?

Tags: the-invention-of-lying

In the Ricky Gervais fantasy alternate reality movie "The Invention of Lying" the filmakers depict a world in which people lack the ability to lie and everything that is said is the absolute truth.  People speak very bluntly including unintentional, but frequently very cruel or cutting comments. In this world, there is no religion, no literature and in fact no fiction at all. The movie industry is limited to documentary style readingss.  Criminals are easily caught as they freely admit to all crimes.

In this world Ricky Gervais' character "Mark" discovers his brain has the ability to lie. We later learn that this ability appears to be a genetic mutation not present in other individuals as evidenced by:

> in the closing scenes we see Mark's son has apparently inherited the ability to lie like his father.

In scenes reminiscient of the short story, "In the Country of the Blind" by H.G. Wells, Mark goes on to find that even with the supposed advantage of being able to lie, things do not always turn out to his benefit.

However, my question is this. Is there a canon explanation (either in-world, or via a valid quote/interview with the writer/director/producer/etc.) which can reconcile the discrepancy of individuals not having the ability to lie, yet apparently having the ability to invent things? E.g. we see cars, movies, etc. in this world. Yet the ability to invent something requires the ability to imagine something that doesn't exist and then make it real. Why should that work for technology and not literature, film, etc.

Lying also generally requires inclusion of the element of deception. I.e. to tell a lie, someone must first know what is true, then mis-represent it. As noted in the comments discussion below, if I print the statement, "Amelia Earhart's fate is unknown. She may have crashed and died. Or, she may have landed and then died from other reasons." that statement is not a lie. Such speculation on the unknown is the basis for much of invention. Will this work or will it not?  Why would that not apply to an entertainment based on the speculation of what might have happened.

Finally, children often make statements which are not lies, but are far from the truth. E.g. if you ask a child how an elevator works, he or she might have some very interesting ideas.  Would it not be possible to film such comments and show them as entertainment?  This would be similar to the recent U.S. television commercials for AT&T which feature an adult posing questions to children. Or the old Art Linkletter (and later Bill Cosby) remake show "Kids say the Darndest Things"

Comment: Surely the essence of the films is that no-one can be deceptive, not that they can't be *creative*. Even the 'documentary style readings' you mentioned feature a skull and a leather-bound book, both of which are stylistic choices. I don't really see this as a valid question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really understanding the question. The inability to create fiction isn't because the people can't be creative, it's because, by definition, fiction is *not true* and the people cannot write or say anything that is not true.

Comment: I wonder how the inventor of The Lie Detector would feel about this...

Comment: I'm more interested in how Zeno's paradox would work in this universe. "If I tell you that I am lying am I telling the truth?"

Comment: @Richard & Michael. Thank you for the feedback/discussion. I can see where you consider a difference between fiction as "not true" and creativity being the discovery of something true.However, I was thinking the process as well as results. Often before finding the successful "truth", invention requires conceiving of ideas/things that turn out to be not true. In that sense, if,as you indicate a person cannot write or say something untrue, then I am trying to understand how they could complete the discovery if it first had to go through a period of "not true" concepts that didn't work?

Comment: For instance Edison thought, "I don't know what will make a good filament. It might be using bamboo. But it might not." Edison knew both could not be be true, but until he experimented, it was an unknown.As a comparable example in literature.We do not know what the "true" reason is for the disappearance of Amelia Earhart.Hence, would it be a lie or untrue to write the statement,"The reason for Amelia Earhart's disappearance is unknown.She might have crashed and died or she might have landed safely." In this case, both cannot be "true". But, I cannot categorically say both are "false", either.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Err...  What does travelling half the distance infinite times have to do with lying?

Comment: Creativity is the idea of making something NEW. Lying and thus fictional writing is the creation of something FALSE. That is the distinction you are trying to make. Creating something that doesn't yet exist is not the same as saying something FALSE when the TRUTH is a known element AND you are compelled by your psychology to tell the TRUTH as you know it.

Comment: I see absolutely no plot inconsistency. Would discovering foods, trying new things, cooking over fire when it hadn't been done before be considered lying to you? If we never created or discovered, we'd (or rather *they'd*) never have survived a winter, much less generations. If you get the wrong answer on a quiz are you lying? NO. You're just wrong. **Ignorance and mendacity are very different things.** The *intent* is the key.

Comment: @Izkata: Zeno came up with more than one paradox, you know. WHich is why I quoted the paradox I was talking about.

Comment: @JamesSheridan I cannot find any indication the lying one was one of them... [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno's_paradox), [2](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-zeno/), [3](http://www.iep.utm.edu/zeno-par/)

Comment: @Izkata - You mean Epimenides, not Zeno. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimenides_paradox

Comment: @JamesSheridan What Richard said

Comment: Also, for the record only bad criminals get caught by admitting their crimes. The good criminals simply avoid getting caught in the first place

Comment: @Richard.  Agreed....unless someone simply asks them if they have committed a crime :-)

Comment: @Richard: Interesting. My 1979 *Columbia* encyclopedia at home attributes it to Zeno. I guess *Wiki* isn't responsible for all misinformation after all.

Answer (score 4):

**Creativity is the idea of making something NEW. Lying and thus fictional writing is the creation of something FALSE.**

That is the distinction you are trying to make. Creating something that doesn't yet exist is not the same as saying something FALSE when the TRUTH is a known element AND you are compelled by your psychology to tell the TRUTH as you know it.

**There could be a way around this psychological block using [supposition and thought-experiments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment) such as Schrödinger's cat.**

- Supposition and thought-experiments are neither true nor false. However, if they were being created as possible ideas stipulating they were TRUE. Then they would be fiction because the idea could not be confirmed.
- Thus the writer would NOT be capable of writing them based on this truth-based psychology. He/She would be unable to fathom the idea AND selling it as TRUTH.

**Filming such ideas might be possible but I suspect there may be undesirable effects in the viewing populace.**

- I suspect it might cause distress in a society where the people have difficulty trying to think about things that **are not true**.
- It might even cause psychological dysfunction the same way "[cognitive dissonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance)" affects people from our world.

**I would think if the society had experimented with such projects and people were negatively affected, they may have simply decided NOT to allow them for "public safety".**

Comment: I think I see what you are getting at and agree on the distinction. Creativity, whether of an invention or art does not solely rely on a conception of something false. E.g. carving something out of stone is not "true" or "false."  But, as a question to you, would you consider the example I wrote above about Amelia Earhart's possible fate to be false?  If yes, why? If not, how would the ability to conceive/document such possible outcomes which cannot shown to be false be different from discussing possible outcomes of an experiment where the results are unknown in advance?

Comment: Supposition and thought-experiments are neither true nor false. However, if they were being created as possible ideas stipulating they were TRUE. Then they would be fiction because the idea could not be confirmed. Thus the writer would NOT be capable of writing them based on this truth-based psychology. He/She would be unable to fathom the idea AND selling it as TRUTH.

Comment: An interesting take. I would agree supposition and thought experiments are neither true or false, hence would be allowed in such a world. Hence, while not stipulating they were true, would you consider it a valid entertainment to film someone making such suppositions and thought experiments?  Not even writing such ideas down because, as you correctly note that could be construed as "fiction", but simply recording the subject speaking about the supposition/thought-experiment?

Comment: I think it might cause distress in a society where the people have difficulty trying to think about things that are not true. It might even cause psychological dysfunction the same way "cognitive dissonance" affects people from our world. I suspect if the society had experimented with such projects and people were negatively affected, they may have simply decided NOT to allow them for "public safety".

Comment: Now that IS an interesting theory! To extend on that, perhaps those individuals that can actually handle some of the dissonance involved in such entertainment might be considered deviant or even perverted. It could explain that such thoughts are possible, but not supported in "polite" company.

Answer (score 2):

**This is an out-of-universe answer based vaguely on real science**

Lying has [a measurable effect on the brain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance#Neuroscience_findings), due to holding two conflicting beliefs, which is called "cognitive dissonance".

I think the key here is "conflicting".

When you lie, you know that the truth is different from what you're saying.  You have to keep them mentally separate, and that creates a small amount of stress on yourself.

Fiction requires [suspension of disbelief](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_of_disbelief) for it to be interesting, which is just a fancy way of saying "lying to yourself for a short time".  So even if they could invent fiction, they couldn't enjoy it, due to being unable to handle the cognitive dissonance it creates.

Creativity, on the other hand, wouldn't create the same conflict, because they're inventing something new.  There's no thought of "I know this won't work", because they *don't* know it won't work.

[To quote Thomas Edison](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/t/thomasaed132683.html),

> I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.

Comment: I like the idea of the congnitive dissonance being a possible driver. I.e. to your point, even if the fiction was somehow created, if the person knew it was false, they couldn't comprehend it.  However, it still raises a question to me. Does stating that Amelia Earhart might have crashed and died or might have landed and then died require a suspension of disbelief?  I.e. if the ultimate "truth" is not known, would that trigger the dissonance?  If not, wouldn't that allow for at least some type of entertainment which focused on discussions of "what might have happened to x?".

Comment: BTW, on the Edison quote, I was thinking of the same one. That Edison did not consider the experiment to be "untrue", only that the results were unknown before he tried them. I.e. before he performed the experiment it was a thought exercise.  Similarly, couldn't we have thought exercises about what might have happened to historical characters with unknown fates? Or, taking it to the next step about what "might" happen to someone in the future? How is that type of exercise a "lie" any more than the light bulb experiments?

Comment: @beichst On the Earhart example, I doubt speculation requires such, but like fiction in general, if they tried to portray the speculation on screen, that itself would be a lie.  [Galaxy Quest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Quest) had a couple good lines about how actors are liars, for example (even though they were talking about plain fiction).  But even when it comes to speculation, what audience would they have?  It may never get created not because they can't create it, but because they couldn't sell it.  Inventors on the other hand are selling a new reality.

Comment: I think you are probably correct that showing such speculation might cross the line into the dissonance factor. That could make it hard/impossible to sell.  Though, it begs the question, whether something can be commercially sold or not, doesn't mean it can't be created or not. In this world we are led to believe such ideas don't exist, not just that they cannot be commercially portrayed on the screen. Again, thank you for the feedback. It is good to have differing questions posed about this.